# Proving NP Completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard, decision-problem

Given $m$ shortest paths between any two vertices of a graph. Determining whether we can pick $k$ shortest paths such that their union covers all edges.

I am trying to reduce set cover problem to it. For a set cover problem we can convert its elements into edges and the set represent a path from the first element to the last one. This conversion of set cover into a graph gives a tree kind of structure. Since between any two nodes in a tree the path is unique so, it has to be shortest as well. I formed a counter example of my own reduction which is given [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8g7j9np9PAsLUVOQmFNTWdTZlk/view?usp=sharing). I believe that I am making some mistake somewhere but unable to recognize it.

Comment: I don't understand your picture. Why is there a group "5,6,7" instead of "5,2" and why is there no group "1,2,3,4"? Those are shortest paths.

Comment: All the closed figures are sets. And I am getting the below graph by converting each set into a path

Comment: I see now. But it may be hard to convert just any group of sets into a "shortest path graph". Maybe it's possible, but not in the straightforward way you did. I'll think about how to prove NP-completeness, but I probably can't be of any help.

Comment: I imagine that you are given *one* shortest path between any pair of vertices, and you are asking whether $k$ of them can cover all edges in the graph. What is the significance of $m$, then? Please clarify your problem statement.

Comment: $m$ is denoting just any arbitrary number of given shortest path. If m is insufficient to cover all edges then result will be false.

Comment: 1. I don't understand the first paragraph.  is it the same two start/end vertices for all $m$ paths?  Or might each of those $m$ paths start and end at different vertices?  What are the inputs?  Are both $m$ and $k$ provided as inputs?  2. What is your question?  3. We ask that questions be self-contained, so they can be understood without having to follow an external link -- both to make it easier for people to understand what you are asking, and also to ensure the question remains comprehensible over time even if the link stops working.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W. Fine, I will take care of that in future. You can find a clearer version of the first paragraph here: https://s15.postimg.org/cgm5vqgrf/Screenshot_from_2016_11_30_21_17_34.png

Comment: Rather than posting a link to a clearer problem statement please edit the post to be as clear and self-contained as possible.  And don't use images as the main content of your question.  Also, make sure to provide proper attribution for your sources!  If this problem came from another source, make sure to credit in the question the source where it came from.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66751/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1926535/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  (Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40888929/781723.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Math.SE and currently has a bounty active there.

Comment: Why are you spoiling things? If don't know the answer then don't reply and carry on. I am spending my reputation there on Math SE because I not getting attention there. Here I am getting more views for it as it is more related to C.S. then why do you want to close it? I don't understand this.

Comment: Please take a look at [the link I provided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068), which explains why cross-posting is not allowed.  I realize that you would prefer to have the post appear on multiple sites (that's understandable), but the community has taken the position that doing so is worse for the Stack Exchange sites and so should not be allowed.

Comment: I completely understand that but what to do If I am not getting a response from anyone at other places. I am bound to post it on other forums. Maybe once I get the answer I will remove duplicates.

Comment: @D.W. If you want I can remove my post from math.exchange right now as my question is not receiving much attention there. You please remove the hold on the post here.

Comment: Your choice.  if you remove it from Math.SE, please flag this for moderator attention and we can re-open it at that time.  Whichever one you want o keep open, I encourage you to edit the question based on the feedback you've already received.  I confess I don't know off-hand whether the bounty will prevent you from deleting the copy on Math.SE; maybe not.